# print on newline with csvwrite in Scilab

Tags: newline, scilab

I have a 5x3 matrix .csv which is correctly read in Scilab. I want to create an output.csv showing the product of the first column multiplied by two, and ignore the other columns.

Trouble is, I want the output to be displayed as a column rather than a row, i.e. instead of 0 1 2 4 8, i want:

0
1
2
4
8 (I guess this doesn't show up as a column, but I want it to be vertical rather horizontal)

I would like to apply '/n', the newline command, in place of the last argument in the csvWrite function, '.', but this doesn't work. I get:

write_csv: Wrong value for input argument #4: '.' or ',' expected.
at line      13 of exec file called by :
exec('C:\Users\afullhar\Documents\Infiltration.sce', -1)

Is there a way to use '\n', or other ways to create column output of my new variable, timetimestwo?

Thanks, My code is below:

```html
//import csv data
data_import = evstr(csvRead('input.csv', ','));


//extraction of columns and definition of variables
time=data_import(:,1)
rate=data_import(:,2)
cumulative=data_import(:,3)

//multiplication of time in hours by 2
timetimestwo=time*2


//export csv and print new variable
csvWrite(timetimestwo','output.csv',' ','.');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `time` is a column vector and use that for the creation of `timetimestwo`, this will also be a column vector. In your `csvWrite` call you transpose the matrix with `'`, see [quote character documentation](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/quote.html). So simply removing `'` character, will result in a non-transposed and thus column vector in the output.

Comment: Thanks, it was the ' character after timetimestwo in csvWrite. I didn't know what this was doing, but as you say, it transposed my output to a row.